# request-promise: Sometimes request is giving EBUSY issue when get/post using API using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, intervals, request-promise

I am using request-promise for Get/Post data to API. Using Interval to for hitting the API URL.
Interval is set for 30 Seconds. Sometimes it giving the EBUSY error with request.

Code:-

```
const request         = require("request-promise");

function getToken(username, password, endpoint) {
    return request({
                       url    : endpoint + "/oauth/token",
                       method : "POST",
                       auth   : { user: username, pass: password },
                       headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                       form   : { type: "client_credentials" }
                   })
        .then(function (result) {
            return result;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // ... error checks
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        });
}
```

Error:-

```
Error: getaddrinfo EBUSY xxxx.xxxx.com\n    at new RequestError (/home/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)\n    at Request.plumbing.callback (/home/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)\n    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/home/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)\n    at self.callback (/home/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)\n    at
at Request.onRequestError (/home/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
(node:6571) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6571) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

> I am also using try {} catch(e){} but its still breaking the interval. 
>  Every time we have to execute it manually on the server after when its stops.

Comment: Can you please post the code itself?

Comment: @SagiRika Hi I have updated my question and added the function which is giving an error.

Comment: I have also put same issue in the request-promise NPM git issues.   https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/333

Comment: Can anyone help me with this, Because of EBUSY my application crashes so many times ?